# Python star unpacking for version 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/431959/386279), you can use the star for unpacking an unknown number of variables (like in functions), but only in python 3:

```
>>> a, *b = (1, 2, 3)
>>> b
[2, 3]
>>> a, *b = (1,)
>>> b
[]
```

In python 2.7, the best I can come up with is (not terrible, but annoying):

```
c = (1, 2, 3)
a, b = c[0], c[1:] if len(c) > 1 else []
```

Is there a way to import this from __future__ like division, or will I need my own function to do unknown-length unpacking in python 2.7?

Comment: No. That's one of the few Py3k *only* features.

Comment: It's called extended unpacking

Answer (score 33, accepted):

in python 2.X, you can do:

```
c = (1, 2, 3)
a, b = c[0], c[1:]
```

as long as `c` has at least one member it will work because if `c` only has 1 thing in it `c[1:]` is `[]`.

You should probably make sure there is at least one thing in `c` though, or else `c[0]` will raise an exception.

You could do something like:

```
try:
    c = tuple(c)
    a, b = c[0], c[1:]
except TypeError, IndexError:
    # c is not iterable, or c is iterable, but it doesn't have any stuff in it.
    # do something else
    pass
```

Comment: Only if `c` is a sequence. Unpacking works with any iterable, so for a full solution, do `c = tuple(c)` first. This emulates the behaviour exactly, including hanging on infinite iterables. But you do still have to work harder for `a, *b, c = range(10)`; but there's no real way around that.

Comment: print ImageFileList
    iflt = tuple(ImageFileList)
    for x,y in iflt[0], iflt[1:]:

why am I still getting an error?
ValueError: too many values to unpack

ImageFileList is just a list of filenames

Answer (score 2):

```
(a,b) = (None, []) if not len(c) else (c[0], c[1:])
```

is also an option for handling the case where c is an empty sequence, although it won't distinguish between [None] and [] in terms as assignments to a, b.  So use it with care, the try / except is probably best.

I can see no real difference between Python 3 and 2.7 when handling an empty container, but the nice thing about Python 3 here is it works with any iterable.

This works in 2.7 if you know c is a generator.

```
a,b = c.next(), c
```

But the full beauty of unpacking seems to require Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

## answer to ex13.py

```
from sys import argv

script=argv

def Fun(arg1, *argv): 
    print "First argument :", script 

    for arg in argv: 
        print"Your variable is:", arg

Fun('scrpit', 'first', 'second', 'third')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.