# Output string.split() into array elements in one line

Tags: python

I have a string `myString`:

```
myString = "alpha beta gamma"
```

I want to split `myString` into its three words:

```
myWords = myString.split()
```

Then, I can access each word individually:

```
firstWord = myWords[0]
secondWord = myWords[1]
thirdWord = myWords[2]
```

**My question**: How can I assign these three words in just one line, as an output from the `split()` function? For example, something like:

```
[firstWord secondWord thirdWord] = myString.split()
```

What's the syntax in Python 2.7?

Comment: What version of python are you running?

Comment: You need to be certain that `split()` will return exactly three arguments, otherwise it's going to fail.

Comment: I am running Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost exactly what you tried works:

```
firstWord, secondWord, thirdWord = myString.split()
```

Demo:

```
>>> first, second, third = "alpha beta gamma".split()
>>> first
'alpha'
>>> second
'beta'
>>> third
'gamma'
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Mr. Pieter's answer and the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122691/output-string-split-into-array-elements-in-one-line/25122996#comment39100653_25122691) raised by TheSoundDefense,

Should `str.split()` return more values than you allow, it will break with `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.  In Python 3 you can do

```
first, second, third, *extraWords = str.split()
```

And this will dump everything extra into a list called `extraWords`.  However, for Python 2 it gets a little more complicated and less convenient as described in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792970/python-star-unpacking-for-version-2-7).

Alternatively, you could change how you're storing the variables and put them in a dictionary using a comprehension.

```
>>> words = {i:word for i,word in enumerate(myString.split())}
>>> words
{0: 'alpha', 1: 'beta', 2: 'gamma'}
```

This has the advantage of avoiding the value unpacking all together (which I think is less than ideal in Python 2).  However, this can obfuscate the variable names as they are now referred to as `words[0]` instead of a more specific name.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is correct also if you want to make a list do this:

```
   my_list=[first, second, third] = "alpha beta gamma".split()
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, using a list comprehension ...

```
mystring = "alpha beta gamma"

myWords = [x for x in mystring.split()]

first = myWords[0]
second = myWords[1]
third = myWords[2]

print(first, second, third)

alpha beta gamma
```

Comment: This list comprehension makes no sense, it just copies the elements from the list returned by `split()` into a new list, and then the list from `split()` is discarded.