# Unable to split a string wirh remainder in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python I have e.g. the following string

```
433 65040    9322 /opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher
```

which I can split according to the following code in python 3:

```
text = " 433 65040    9322 /opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher"
pid,rss,etime,*remainder = text.split()
```

However, when I try the same in python 2.7.12, I get a SyntaxError:

```
In [1]: text = " 433 65040    9322 /opt/conda/envs/python2/bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher"

In [2]: a,b,c,*d = text.split()
   File "<ipython-input-2-a87c46b7bdb7>", line 1
    a,b,c,*d = text.split()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I do that in python2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792970/python-star-unpacking-for-version-2-7

Comment: I will just do it in five lines, simple splicing...

Comment: Star unpacking is not supported by python 2.7.

Comment: Yes I learned that. But the second linked question has the answer I am using...